# How can I use 'authorities' in MuleESB

Tags: spring, security, authorization, mule, esb

I'm using MuleESB 3.4.1 now. I want add a inbound-endpoint filter for authorization.

I've added following codes:

```
<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="inmemory-provider" delegate-ref="validateAuthenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<flow name="add-flow" doc:name="add-flow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8081" path="add" doc:name="Add Request">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"
            securityProviders="inmemory-provider" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
</flow>

<ss:authentication-manager alias="validateAuthenticationManager">
    <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service>
            <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <ss:user name="staff" password="staff" authorities="ROLE_STAFF" />
        </ss:user-service>
    </ss:authentication-provider>
</ss:authentication-manager>
```

How can I allow ROLE_ADMIN to request but not ROLE_STAFF?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the mule-ss:authorization-filter in your http:inbound-endpoint.

```
<flow name="add-flow" doc:name="add-flow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    host="localhost" port="8081" path="add" doc:name="Add Request">
    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"
        securityProviders="inmemory-provider" />
    <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</http:inbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have optional roles? i.e. If i want to allow users with either the `ROLE_ADMIN` or the `ROLE_USER` role?